# How to pass socket from JFrame to another JFrame Java socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I create program chat box, `client` will send code to `server` after that `server` will return `object` to `client`;
I use JFrame to create `login.java`. This frame will create new `client` and send this `client` to  JFrame `chatbox.java`. `chatbox` will get data from `server` and `server` will get data from database.

`database`<--->`server` <---> `client` <---> JFrame.

But when I pass `client` from `login.java` to `chatbox.java` the `server` will create new socket. Then will make 2 socket run for 1 Jframe(wasted thread). How can I solve this problem or can you give me some ways to make this program! Thanks all

Code demo:

**Server**

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        ExecutorService excutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);
            System.out.println("Server success");
            while (true) {

                Socket socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("connect success");

                ThreadHandler thread = new ThreadHandler(socket);

                excutor.execute(thread);

                System.out.println("============");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadHandler extends Thread {
    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dataOut;
    private DataInputStream dataIn;
    private ObjectInputStream objIn;
    private ObjectOutputStream objOut;
    private volatile boolean stop = false;
    UserDAO userDAO;
    User userSave ;
    public ThreadHandler(Socket sockets) {
        this.socket = sockets;
        try {
            dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            userDAO = new UserDAO();
            userSave = new User();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error in constructor");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                String code = dataIn.readUTF();
                switch (code) {
                    case "login":
                        try {
                            User user = (User) objIn.readObject();
                            this.userSave = user;
                            User userLogin = userDAO.loginUser(user);
                            objOut.writeObject(userLogin);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                        break;
                    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    userDAO.setStatusUser(false, userSave); //set account offline in db
                    dataIn.close();
                    objIn.close();
                    objOut.close();
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client {

    DataOutputStream dataOut;
    DataInputStream dataIn;
    ObjectInputStream objIn;
    ObjectOutputStream objOut;
    Socket socket;

    public Client() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    

    public User loginUser(User user) {
        User fullUser = null;
        try {
            dataOut.writeUTF("login");
            objOut.writeObject(user);
            fullUser = (User) objIn.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        return fullUser;
    }
```

**JFrame**

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Client client;
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        client = new Client();
        this.setTitle("Login to TCS");
}
//bt login
private void btLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       String login = tfLogin.getText();
       String password = String.copyValueOf(tfPassword.getPassword());
       if(login.isEmpty()||password.isEmpty()){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Plz enter account!");
           return;
       }else{
           User user = new User(login, password);
           User userLogin = client.loginUser(user);
           if(userLogin == null){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your login or password is invalid!");
               
           }else{
               ListOfUser listOfUser = new ListOfUser(userLogin, client);//pass client to chatbox
               listOfUser.setVisible(true);
               this.dispose();
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have this line (in method `btLoginActionPerformed`): `Client client = new Client();`

Comment: I also don't know when I added it :( Thank you for helping me find it

Comment: @Abra
Maybe my problem has been solved